# Only one from each set

Tags: code-golf, set-theory

Your input is a non-empty set of non-empty sets of positive integers. For example:

```
{{1}, {2, 3}, {2,4}, {1,4}}
```

Your task is to output the maximal number of elements that can be picked from the sets with the following conditions:

- You can only pick at most 1 element from a set
- You can't pick the same element from 2 different sets

In this example you can pick `1` from the first set, `3` from the second set, `2` from the third set and `4` from the last set, for a total of 4 elements.

Io is flexible. You can take a list, instead of sets, etc.

There are no gaps in the numbers (eg. `{{2,3},{3,4}}` is not a valid input). Or in other words, the input flattened must contain all numbers `[1,n]` where n is the largest number in the input.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

## Examples

```
{{1}}
-> 1

{{1}, {2, 3}, {2,4}, {1,4}}
-> 4

{{1}, {2}, {1,2,3,4}}
-> 3

{{1}, {2}, {2,3}}
-> 3

{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}}
-> 5

{{1,2,3,4,5}, {1,2}, {2,3}, {1,3}}
-> 4

{{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,3},{2,4},{3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4},{5,6,7,8,9,10}}
-> 5

{{1,4}, {2,3}, {1,3}, {1,2,3}}
-> 4
```

## Background

Recently [@AnishSharma](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110533/anish-sharma) posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814560/select-one-element-from-each-set-but-the-selected-element-should-not-be-repeated/70814859) question on Stack Overflow. This is a slightly modified version of that question

Comment: Is it acceptable to output a selection of the maximum number instead of the number?

Comment: Do you mean like a set of picks? If so, the answer is no, just output the length of that set.

Comment: Is "`3` from the second set, `2` from the second set" a typo for "`3` from the second set, `2` from the third set"?

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 66 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(map(len,map(set,product(*x))))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NDoIwFIT3nOIti5mFUPAv8STIAhUiCaVNqUkN4ewILUSjXfTrTF9mWvUyD9nysTpfxqYQ13tB9iQKy0ShWFO2mNmVBkrL@/Nm2MaG0woqLQXVptRGyqajWiipzWZUum4NyypmQ6qkJkt1S1mQ9dGQwwHUxyDumcyIJnxdeisG/7cnc7FAnxBKQCloNyvuj6C9j6H4uzCauQS4AqRL25ru1GdmgJNwb4Sf8M/uudtdzkKv@TrpmGKHPQ44ItquqclP2frfIQ/yPBzf)

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 6 bytes

```
ŒpQ€ẈṀ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLFknBR4oKs4bqI4bmAIiwiIiwiIixbIltbMSwgMiwgM10sIFsyLCA0LCA1LCA2XSwgWzMsIDUsIDYsIDddLCBbMSwgMl0sIFsyLCAzXSwgWzEsIDNdXSJdXQ==)

```
ŒpQ€ẈṀ    Main Link
Œp        Cartesian Product; get all possible selections
  Q€      Uniquify each
    Ẉ     Length of each
     Ṁ    Maximum result
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
f=lambda s,*v:s and max(f(s[1:],x,*v)for x in s[0])or len({*v})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVDLDoMgELz3K/YIZg9S7MvELyEcaNTURNGIMTZNv50iio099DLDzu4sk@2ew6PV3Noyq1VzzxUYjMbUgNI5NGoiJTGCpRInJ9Oy7WGCSoMRsaSuqAtNXtH4pnYozGAgAyGYlOgJxRG5x8Qhc/hteMG1f8XZsQi4mfGEZ/fiM@NlcW7L2c4wD/8ZWMslzD4eX0MGUwjNw6RnnwCveEMWh63J7quwQx4OXV/pgYiSTBS2y/k7SWo/)

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 10 bytes

```
xMl<nb<<sQ
```

Works as of commit [4a9f6d27](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library/-/commit/4a9f6d27aecd3e27a45fb7168355f67cd8ad6993).  Older version below.

### Explanation

The functions involved are:

- `sQ`  can do many things but on lists it performs the cartesian product.
- `nb` removes all duplicate lements from a list.
- `xMl` gets the length of the longest list in a list of lists

So we get the Cartesian product, nub the results and then get the maximum of their lengths.

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 13 bytes

```
mx<l.^nb.^sQ
```

This no longer works in recent versions of hgl since `(.^)` was renamed to `(<<)`.  To test it run:

```
mx<l<<nb<<sQ
```

### Explanation

This works the same as the new implementation above except we have to get all the lengths and then get the maximum separately. The new functions are:

- `l` gets the length of a list
- `mx` gets the maximum of a list.

So we get the Cartesian product, nub the results and then get the maximum of their lengths.

### Reflections

- First things first we don't have a set type.  This is unfortunate and needs to be fixed at some point.
- `l<nb` seems like something that would be useful to have a builtin for.
- It would be nice to have some sort fold and sequence or fold and traverse combined function.
- <s>I could have used a "maxmap".  If we wanted to get the actual choices we could have done, `xB l<nb.^sQ` to save two bytes.  But `xB` returns the original list not the modified version.</s> This has been fixed in newer versions with the function is called `xM`, but `xMl` was also added which saves another byte.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 70 bytes

Expects an array of arrays.

```javascript
f=([b,...a],s)=>b?Math.max(...b.map(v=>f(a,new Set(s).add(v)))):s.size
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZM9b4MwEIb3/AqPRro6dUz6KcjUsVNGy8MBpkmV4ihGpOqfJweBUIYOFdxwPlnW896H7xMr9OlpfyzvCpfZus4jrhMQQqABH0RxsnnHcie@8JvTZULBkVdRnHOEwp7Z1pbcBwKzjFcB2YsXfv9j61e9YExraQywmW25ZLKDg16Ban1IXpKfKkfwcIC3UJKYAdzB1QjeZD9XgwY43JoCa3igSDUnPF6ruTVN/kOc4OsB3oAnwP7uOaw61HWY4/Gqbsi9YD901b9sz7ZSeIJnkPdNRr8yD0fZ9igz9beYhcjd6Q3THUcWxSx1hXcHKw7ug9Oa0FLUFw)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (              // f is a recursive function taking:
  [b,              //   b[] = next list
      ...a],       //   a[] = all remaining lists
  s                //   s = current set, initially undefined
) =>               //
b ?                // if b[] is defined:
  Math.max(        //   return the maximum of ...
    ...b.map(v =>  //     for each value v in b[]:
      f(           //       do a recursive call:
        a,         //         pass a[]
        new Set(s) //         create a new set from s
                   //         (an empty set if s is undefined)
        .add(v)    //         add v to it
      )            //       end of recursive call
    )              //     end of map()
  )                //   end of Math.max()
:                  // else:
  s.size           //   return the size of s
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to pajonk*

```r
function(x)max(lengths(apply(expand.grid(x),1,table)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdDoIwDIXvfYom3mxJNY5toBf6LsifJHMSwASffg4YQwJetVu/np62NvnV5G@dtOVLk44@446oTBftoyFxVakPyboq1umxqMvU1pFhG99VRik1OVFl05KEMPvaH27AdrufP4SEBMhdFENkNo6sWLOOsD2e4n@oXneDQAgQpokgECRCODz5mCNEbgpMQo5nfTJKyoXkYAflZG6xFvM2xLLHV6elt47B/VFmvflQfO5ymcQQIzzjBdlp06pYmZvlnU3zBQ)

Test setup stolen from [pajonk's R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/241642/95126).
48 bytes using [R](https://www.r-project.org/) ≥ 4.1 by exchanging `function` for `\`.

Comment: TIL about `lengths` function. Thanks!

Comment: @pajonk - You're welcome.  It's quite disconcerting when you accidentally learn something potentially useful while deliberately trying to write difficult-to-understand code, isn't it?  This has often happened to me, too...

Comment: You're absolutely right... BTW, you "stole" the test setup from me, but not the `table` function (for -1) ;-)

Comment: @pajonk - Dang, you're right!  But if I use ```table``` instead of ```unique```, it'd be the same as you using ```lengths``` instead of ```sapply(,length)```...  we should flip a coin somehow do decide who gets to use the other's function...

Comment: @pajonk - You win and get to use ```lengths``` (& the 54-byte solution) if you guess correctly whether or not my secret string ```s``` ends with an odd-indexed letter (```a```, ```c```, ```e``` ... ```y```), where ```echo "```...```s```...```" | sha256sum``` gives ```c7cfcd989367e4b325cb659c85e6c865a13f6fb57a2fd4c912d272981ecf8d6a```.  Approach from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/239228)...

Comment: I think it was your comment on some of my past answers that taught me to use `table` when I wanted to use `unique` (but I cannot find it now), so I am willing to give up the 54-byte solution on your behalf. However, if you still insist on settling this with a coin toss, you may take the index of the last letter in this comment.

Comment: "[pajonk_guesses_heads](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19BqSAxKz8vOz69NLW4OLU4PiM1MaVYSaFGoTgj0cjUrLg09/9/AA)" ends in letter ```s``` ≠ ```t``` (by odd/even position).

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 42 bytes

```
[ [ members ] product-map longest length ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVG7DsIwENv5Cv8AiFLefABiYUFMiCGUo1SkaUiOAap@e6EPmiIYmGw5tu9OOYmAE5NvN6v1cg5L1xupgGxPm@R4CxghKTJCRg/BUaLsy8EWFzKKpHNDG2K@axMpxqLTSZHCQ4asYSkG8GscluiV@Omo9ML5@63qeOvtxhHGJfdLNmma2pO9r3SR@8fptPfe3/f4zV2uxd3qt1IVq/acYgav3xo2/LGIK83yHXaIKT6Qsdij/qVuLDRkokKyDEkq5DP2@RRKaC3v6FkEkoTJnw)

Uniqueify the elements of the product sequence of the input, then find the longest length.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 60 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 53 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with a `\`.

```r
function(x)max(sapply(apply(expand.grid(x),1,table),length))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDbDoIwDIbvfYom3mxJNY5toBf6LshJkokEMMGnn8AOSMCbtdu@/v3bRudXnb@rpCtfFenpM@5JG9e1@hBzZn0dV@mxaMp0@EaGXXxXGUWVVUX3oFTnRJVtRxLCKKX7ww3YbvfzhpCQALmNYopsiIYVa9YSQ42n@B9q1N0gEAIE1xEEgkQIpys3OUJku4ATsjwbEyMpF5KTHZTO3GIs5m2IZY3/dUNvLYP7pcx686L4XGUziSFGeMYLstOmVbEyN8tbm/oL)

---

Solution shorter in [R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1:

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 66 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 52 bytes** by replacing two `function` occurrences with `\`s.

```r
function(x)max(apply(expand.grid(x),1,function(a)sum(table(a)|1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDbDoIwDIbveYom3mxJNY4N0At9l8nBkAASDgkmvvscMDYJeNWu@/r3bxuV3VTWV3GXvyoy0FIORNZ18SbpUMsqOT2bPNF1ZGgpSdu@JJ18FKnOP4xSqjJS5G1HYjK@Dsc7MM/7qSHExEduopgi03FmxZY1hO6xFP9Djbo7BIKPsEwEgRAghNOTzzlCZKbAImR4NiazZLCSnOxgsJhbrcWsDbHusb/L0nvH4PYoTs8dirsukwUYYoQXvCI771oVG3NO3thUXw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
Πv‡ULG
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLOoHbigKFVTEciLCIiLCJbWzFdLCBbMiwgM10sIFsyLCA0XSwgWzEsIDRdXSJd)

```
Π      # Cartesian product - get all possibilties
 v     # Over each...
  ‡--  # Do the next two elements
   U   # Uniquify 
    L  # Get length
     G # Maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 32 bytes

```
Ｉ⌈ＥＥΠＥθＬιＥθ§λ÷ι∨ΠＥ…θμＬν¹ＬΦι⁼μ⌕ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUxdC4MwDPwrfWwhg6n7ZE/DTRA25rv4ULTMQq2zVnG/vtPQDRbI3eWSXFlzU7ZcOZcZqS2NeW/pnU@yGZqZX9iZaauhtKg7IDehn7amkjEGxHtnm@pKTFQBSbW9yFFWgkogD/P3Hb9LJeK6xZ@G/bI0ZgWMIXszkcoKs6Rcu4GrnjZAEqmrxVHM18m5PM8DCAuYMULczBiiDlFHiPON34d@jr6XyFvYwR4OcIRgXRSFW43qAw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
      θ                             Input array
     Ｅ                              Map over lists
        ι                           Current list
       Ｌ                            Take the length
    Π                               Take the product
   Ｅ                                Map over implicit range
          θ                         Input array
         Ｅ                          Map over lists
            λ                       Current list
           §                        Cyclically indexed by
              ι                     Outer value
             ÷                      Integer divided by
                   θ                Input array
                  …                 Truncated to length
                    μ               Inner index
                 Ｅ                  Map over array
                      ν             Innermost list
                     Ｌ              Take the length
                Π                   Take the product
               ∨                    Logical Or
                       ¹            Literal integer `1`
  Ｅ                                 Map over lists
                          ι         Current list
                         Φ          Filtered where
                            μ       Inner index
                           ⁼        Equal to
                             ⌕      Index of
                               λ    Inner value
                              ι     In current list
                        Ｌ           Take the length
 ⌈                                  Take the maximum
Ｉ                                   Cast to string
                                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.»âε¸˜Ùg}à
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79Duw4vObT204/ScwzPTaw8v@P8/OtowVifaSMcYTJoASUMoaRwbCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/vUO7Dy86t/XQjtNzDs9Mrz284L/O/@joaMPYWB0FEKUTbaRjDCZNgKQhkERIgAWA0uiCIB0QAR24Zh1THTMgyxhE65hDdMINN0TRAFKMRwGUC3EMqvOMoY6EaYI52himEkyDXaBjoWOpY2gAM9UExSqYGbGxAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.»     # (Left-)reduce the (implicit) input-list by:
  â    #  Cartesian product
ε      # Then map over each inner list:
 ¸     #  Wrap it into a list (workaround for input [[1]])
  ˜    #  Flatten it
   Ù   #  Uniquify it
    g  #  Pop and push the length
}à     # After the map: pop and push the maximum
       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 55

```
J(l)=maximum(length.(Set.(Iterators.product(l...))[:]))
```

[ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVI9T8MwEBUj-RWWJ0e6RqRJ2oKUiLUgxMBYOpjWhYDrRrbDh0J_CUuX_qgy8FvwR0ILI0ve3bu79852PraPNS_p5vPoqRRVLlnF6YwRSV8wxk0Tr9e9AsWBjQA1fUCJx9RCbMDW05-6Z_uQtJXkV8XwexbQXg2lgDJAA5slPgQ09GKof-gcW7QamdNwTpC1tp2Hy5L9arbiGHArg2_yp2gS93VSLfo86TodZjCAIYzgFOKTA__0j2V3fO9trhBQgBucF3hiQry20RSH21oveqPd8ILwMF_S13JZLwln4l4_ROSG6YiMNZNUr6SKKrma1zNNeBRFYTg5m4bd-FclS6G5aF_rn2Jm8r3w7WZDdPemmcJhsFhJNKMKlQKpipeamN8D8K0wpWMOVKjc06YHcK9wdM6eKSdXTNOoolIxs5Chba9Px0LbScOdU6WY1MTtnDuOiXnQHQhfX3aXtNl4_AY)